# How to create a receiving address using the Bitcoin Core client?

Tags: bitcoin-core, receiving

Im new on bitcoin 1-2 years ago I used bitpay and coinbase but now Im trying to get the wallet directly on my macbook.Downloaded the bitcoin core from bitcoin.com
[image: w]

So, Im registered on https://gourl.io to use a plugin for the wordpress but in their site, a field in the form is asking me for the external wallet address.

Any one is selling digital products using edd and gourl.io ?
Can some one explain what should I do and where can I find my wallet address?

Thank you!

Comment: no idea of gourl.io, but your wallet address is in the menu -> file -> receive addresses ...

Comment: So I have to create an address there? Because in that section I have empty fields https://preview.ibb.co/fwawHb/Schermata_2017_11_02_alle_21_30_13.png

Comment: no, you are in the bitcoin window. The top menu line (next to the apple in the top left corner) says Bitcoin Core, then File, ... not sure what it is in Italian. See here: https://ibb.co/gn4sOG

Comment: If you want your question about selling digital products answered, you should ask it as a separate question.

Comment: @pebwindkraft thankyou very much I understood all and I found what I was looking for looking on your screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click "Receive" tab >>> Click "Request payment" button

Note: "Label", "Amount" and "Message" fields are optional

---

View Receiving Addresses: "File" >>> "Receiving addresses..."